# Using AppleScript with administrator privileges, "not ask for authentication again for five minutes." doesn't work?

Tags: applescript

in Apple Document [Technical Note 2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-HOW_DO_I_GET_ADMINISTRATOR_PRIVILEGES_FOR_A_COMMAND_), it mention "do shell script command with administrator privileges"，when using this way，"Once a script is correctly authenticated, it will not ask for authentication again for five minutes."

but, it still need ask for authentication again and again.

I find，when use ScriptEditor.app, the Apple Document is right.
eg:
`do shell script "/bin/cp -r /Users/Simon/Desktop/Test/test.zip /Users/Simon/Desktop/ " with administrator privileges`

but, when use NSAppleScript running shell script, the Apple Document is wrong.
eg:

```
    NSDictionary *error = nil;
NSString *copyScript = @"do shell script \"/bin/cp -r /Users/Simon/Desktop/Test/test.zip /Users/Simon/Desktop \" with administrator privileges";
NSAppleScript *copyAppleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:copyScript];
if ([copyAppleScript executeAndReturnError:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"copyAppleScript Success!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"copyAppleScript Failuer!");
}
```

I hope, when do shell script with NSAppleScript, it will not ask for authentication again for five minutes also.

Comment: I'm confused by this phrase: " it still need ask for authentication". Do you mean that your script *does* repeatedly ask for authentication, and you don't want it to? Or do you mean that you want it to repeatedly ask for authentication, and it *doesn't*?

Comment: I describe the problem again. Thank you @Ted Wrigley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think this is the best way to approach this problem. But let me answer the question first, and then suggest another avenue.

Note that tech note 2065 says this:

> The authentication only applies to that specific script: a different
>   script, or a modified version of the same one, will ask for its own
>   authentication.

Every time you run this line:

```
NSAppleScript *copyAppleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:copyScript];
```

...you create a new script, and that *new* script will need authorization of its own. If you want to reuse a given script without constantly reauthorizing, you'll need to create an `NSAppleScript` property, store your script there once, and then call it repeatedly.  In other words:

```cpp
@interface MyObject ()

@property (strong) NSAppleScript *myAppleScript;

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (void)setUpScript {
    // call this once
    NSDictionary *error = nil;
    NSString *copyScript = @"do shell script \"/bin/cp -r /Users/Simon/Desktop/Test/test.zip /Users/Simon/Desktop \" with administrator privileges";
    self.myAppleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:copyScript];
}

- (void)runScript {
    // call this as needed; shouldn't need reauthorization
    if ([self.myAppleScript executeAndReturnError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"myAppleScript Success!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"myAppleScript Failure!");
    }
}

@end
```

However, since your goal here is to run a shell script, I'd suggest you forget about `NSAppleScript` entirely, and use [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask) instead. `NSTask` is how shell scripts are meant to be run from objC, and should avoid authorization problems entirely. The easiest way to do this is to write an explicit shell script and store it in the bundle:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cp -r /Users/Simon/Desktop/Test/test.zip /Users/Simon/Desktop
```

Then call and run that shell script:

```cpp
NSError *err;
NSTask *task = [NSTask launchedTaskWithExecutableURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ShellScript"
                                                                             withExtension:@"sh"]
                                           arguments:[NSArray array]
                                               error:&err
                                  terminationHandler:nil];
```

...or maybe this, if you don't want to bundle a script...

```cpp
NSError *err;
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init]
task.arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"#!/bin/bash",
                  @"-c",
                  @"cp -r /Users/Simon/Desktop/Test/test.zip /Users/Simon/Desktop",
                  nil];
[task launchAndReturnError:&err];
```

**P.S.**

I've been assuming that this `cp` command is just proof-of-concept, but if your actual goal is to copy a file, forget about `NSAppleScript` *and* `NSTask`. Use [`NSFileManager's`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager) `copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:` instead.

Comment: thanks a lot，you‘re great！From your beautiful answer，I understand that the Apple Document is right。In fact，my demand is that copying a file to  '/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL',  this operation need admin permission。NSFileManager doesn't satisfy my demand。and another demand is that when show the alert window of authority，I can change the alert window's promt，eg：do shell script "/bin/cp -r /Users/Simon/Desktop/Test/test.zip  /Library/ " with prompt "changed title" with administrator privileges。 So， the way of NSAppleScript satisfies my demand。