# Multiple Using AppleScript with administrator privileges

Tags: applescript

I have several commands that have to be run using admin:
Such as silently installing packages, creating folders as administrators, restarting some services, etc.
I think when using the administrator to run the shell command for the first time, after the user successfully enters the administrator password, it is no longer necessary for subsequent times.

I see similar questions [not ask for authentication again for five minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214232/using-applescript-with-administrator-privileges-not-ask-for-authentication-aga) ,but not satisfied.

```html
- (void)setUpScript {
    // call this once
    NSDictionary *error = nil;
    NSString *copyScript = @"do shell script \"/bin/cp -r /Users/Simon/Desktop/Test/test.zip /Users/Simon/Desktop \" with administrator privileges";
    self.myAppleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:copyScript];
}

- (void)runScript {
    // call this as needed; shouldn't need reauthorization
    if ([self.myAppleScript executeAndReturnError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"myAppleScript Success!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"myAppleScript Failure!");
    }
}
```

As i see this code.The variable "myAppleScript" it is fixed.I need to change its script content.But if I reinitialize "myAppleScript", the key window appears.Am I understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation: Technical Note TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html) explains it clearly

> Once a script is correctly authenticated, it will not ask for authentication again for five minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the answer in the link seems to only apply to the case of repeated invocations of the same shell instruction, not multiple different shell instruction invocations as I said.

Comment: No, it applies to any subsequent call inside the 5 minute range but you have always specify `with administrator privileges` in the shell script lines.

Comment: @Zolrath It only applies to a single *AppleScript*, but that AppleScript can run as many different shell commands as it wants (within 5 minutes).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Forgive me for being a beginner.I see what you're saying, but instead of calling multiple sudo shells in a single AppleScript, I'm calling multiple AppleScripts as needed in the running application.